# El índice estaba fuera del intervalo no debe ser negativo y menor que el tamaño del nombre del parámetro de colección El índice

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hola buenos dias tengo este error intento borrar de una base de datos un registro lo hago con una funcion que es la siguiente en la que @iddetalle lo deve de tomar de del programa para eliminarlo lo mas raro es que solo un formulario el que presento ese problema con los demas formularios no presentan ese problema
y cuando ejecuto el eliminar desde sql manager si me lo acepta no se que pueda estar pasando

```
[dbo].[eliminar_detalle_venta]
 @iddetalle_venta as integer
  as
   delete from detalle_venta where iddetalle_venta =@iddetalle_venta
```

Este es el comando que estoy usando para declarar la funcion en mi programa:

```
 Public Function eliminar(ByVal dts As vdetalle_venta) As Boolean
        Try
            conectar()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("eliminar_detalle_venta")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Connection = cnn

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@iddetalle_venta", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dts.giddetalle_venta
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Los siguientes comandos son los que ocupo para llamar la funcion en mi programa

```
  Private Sub BtnQuitar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnQuitar.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult
    result = MessageBox.Show("¿Realmente desea eliminar los ventas seleccionados?", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Datalistado.Rows
                Dim marcado As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("eliminar").Value)
                If marcado Then
                    Dim onekey As Integer = Convert.ToUInt32(row.Cells("iddetalle_venta").Value)
                    Dim vdb As New vdetalle_venta
                    Dim func As New fdetalle_venta
                    vdb.giddetalle_venta = onekey
                    vdb.gidproducto = Datalistado.SelectedCells.Item(3).Value
                    vdb.gidventa = Datalistado.SelectedCells.Item(2).Value
                    vdb.gcantidad = Datalistado.SelectedCells.Item(5).Value
                    vdb.gprecio_unitario = Datalistado.SelectedCells.Item(6).Value
                    If func.eliminar(vdb) Then
                        If func.aumentar_stock(vdb) Then

                        End If
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("El articulo seleccionados fue quitado de la venta", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    End If

                End If
            Next
            Call mostrar()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelar eliminacion de registro", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Call mostrar()
    End If
    Call limpiar()
End Sub
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Creo que el problema puede ser con este código `Datalistado.SelectedCells.Item(6).Value`, pero no estoy seguro. Lo que sí es seguro es que no es un error de SQL.

Comment: @LuisCazares en un inicio la tenia agregada y me estaba saliendo ese error y dije alomejor que me falte ese y se la puse pero igual no creo que se por hay mi error

Comment: Son los lugares que tienen índices. Revisa la longitud de ese array. Creo que faltaría más información para responder.

Comment: gracias ya quedo ahora tengo otro problema pero voy hacer otra pregunta para ese problema esta pregunta ya quedo resulta y si tenias razon pero era quitar todo el datalistado

Comment: Escribe la solución como respuesta para que sirva a otros que puedan tener un problema similar

Answer (score 0):

la solucion a mi problema es el siguiente codigo aunque ahorita  se presento otro error pero para resolver este problema es el siguiente  comandos:

```
Private Sub BtnQuitar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnQuitar.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult
    result = MessageBox.Show("¿Realmente desea eliminar los ventas seleccionados?", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Datalistado.Rows
                Dim marcado As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("eliminar").Value)
                If marcado Then
                    Dim onekey As Integer = Convert.ToUInt32(row.Cells("iddetalle_venta").Value)
                    Dim vdb As New vdetalle_venta
                    Dim func As New fdetalle_venta
                    vdb.giddetalle_venta = onekey


                    If func.eliminar(vdb) Then
                        If func.aumentar_stock(vdb) Then

                        End If
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("El articulo seleccionados fue quitado de la venta", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    End If

                End If
            Next
            Call mostrar()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelar eliminacion de registro", "Eliminar registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Call mostrar()
    End If
    Call limpiar()
End Sub
```

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen solo código, sin explicar cómo ese código resuelve el problema o cual era el fallo del código de la pregunta tienden a considerarse de baja calidad. Encontrarás más información en [answer].